# Generating a list of links to be displayed in Facelets

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, facelets

I need to have a list of links generated by JSF and displayed in Facelets.  The bean would contain all of the links and where they need to point to, and then I assume some method would run to disperse all of them which could be called by some JSF attribute in the Facelets page.

I'm kind of clueless. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ui:repeat` tag:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.links}" var="link" varStatus="status">
    <h:outputLink value="#{link.url}">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{link.name}"/>
    </h:outputLink>
    <h:outputText value=", " rendered="#{not status.last}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

`bean` is managed bean that have `getLinks` method. `getLinks` method returns list of links. Every link is an object with `name` and `url` properties. All links are separated by commas.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink to see when to use outputLink and when to use commandLink

Comment: Remember that the link.url must evaluate to a defined navigation rule or, in JSF2, to a page's name to use implicit navigation.

Comment: Oh nice!  Very convenient.  Thanks much!